# How to construct the -ish form of a compund adjective?

Tags: compound-adjectives

Will it be yellow-greenish, yellowish-greenish or yellowish-green?

Comment: Usually I've seen the "-ish" form precede the adjective, but for common color combinations (like "yellow-green") one could also add -ish to the end. What has your own research turned up?

Comment: Since *-ish* is a very informal usage, any answer will be subjective.  That said, it sounds more natural to use it only once-- *yellowish-green* to describe a shade of green that is more yellow than other greens, *greenish-yellow* to describe a shade of yellow that is more green than other yellows. *Yellowish-greenish* is even more informal and implies that you don't really know the color, and are trying to describe it to someone.

Comment: Your distinction between yellowish green and greenish yellow seems to be correct. However, the compound adjective itself is not in the -ish form. As in, 'yellowish green' cannot be directly substituted in a sentence where 'yellowish' is being used.

Comment: Surely if you have to (and I'm not sure why you would), it would be *yellow-green-ish*, which follows the convention of simply adding *-ish* to the end of whatever it is, *yellow-green* in this case.